# If all features of a kernel $k$ are contained in a RKHS $H$, does then $H(k)\subset H$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $k_1$ and $k_2$ be symmetric positive definite kernels on a set $X$, denote the corresponding RKHS's by $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively, and also denote the canonical feature maps by $\Phi_1 : X\to H_1$ and $\Phi_2 : X\to H_2$, respectively.

> Assume that $\Phi_1(x)\in H_2$ for all $x\in X$. Does it then follow that $H_1\subset H_2$?

My kernels are actually Gaussian, so we may assume that $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^d$, for example $\mathbb R^d$ itself or the closed or open unit ball.

I tried a lot, but either I am too dumb to prove this, or it is just false. At least I know that the condition gives me
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n\alpha_i\alpha_j k_1(x,y_i)k_1(x,y_j)\,\le\,c^2\sum_{i,j=1}^n\alpha_i\alpha_j k_2(y_iy_j)
$$
for some $c>0$ and all $\alpha_i\in\mathbb R$, all $y_i\in X$ and all $x\in X$. However, what I want is
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n\alpha_i\alpha_j k_1(y_i,y_j)\,\le\,c^2\sum_{i,j=1}^n\alpha_i\alpha_j k_2(y_iy_j),
$$
because this is equivalent to $H_1\subset H_2$.

In the case of Gaussian kernels, I tried to integrate the first one w.r.t. some probability measure over $X=\mathbb R^d$, but didn't succeed.

Comment: My prior comment was indeed confused - sorry for that. The set inclusion is $H_1^0\subset H_2.$ And my point was: Why should this inclusion tell you anything about the topology or geometry of $H_1^0$  with respect to the topology/geometry of $H_2$? The inner products need not be related, i.e. there is no relation between $\langle \Phi_1(x), \Phi_1(y)\rangle_1$ and $\langle \Phi_1(x), \Phi_1(y)\rangle_2$, except the fact that you know that the latter inner product is defined.

Comment: @gg How would $H_1\subset H_2$ imply a relation between those two inner products?

Comment: If $H_1\subset H_2$  the inclusion map is bounded. From this you can conclude that a constant $c>0$ exists such that $k_1 \leq c^2 k_2.$ See Theorem 5.1 in [Paulsen, V. I. and Raghupathi](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316219232)

Comment: With Google books you can even see the proof https://books.google.ch/books?id=rEfGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%22Aronszajn+inclusion+theorem%22&source=bl&ots=0Lg6MsChGx&sig=ACfU3U2rbo-lsYizOIATKFj-xaxG92O6zQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjniIrhncSCAxU2_7sIHeF2CP8Q6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Aronszajn%20inclusion%20theorem%22&f=false

Comment: @gg I know this. But how does this help? The relation $k_1\le c^2 k_2$ is exactly the last formula in my question. Do you have a counterexample?